# How to install window 7 without formatting my D:drive (that contains my personal data _not OS file)?

Tags: windows-7

I know how to backup C:drive as win7 creates window.old file as backup but what if have to backup my other drive ((partition)) and install win7 without harming my data in that drive.

Comment: Windows will only affect the partition you select to install it on.  It does not does other partition.  The best way to install Windows is on a disk without any partitions, this way all required partitions, can be created.  If you don't do this you might be shocked at the layout of the partitions once you get into Windows.

Answer (score -1):

If you have `1 physical hardrive` with 2 partition or `2 physical hardrive`, during installation you can select and format only the drive C: or the hardrive you want to install the OS so that your drive D: with your backup will be safe.

You may want to rename your backup drive so that you can specify that drive during installation.

[image]